# Target element when inside v-for loop Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to build a To-Do list in Vue.js which has 3 columns: To-Do, Doing, Done.

I would like to be able to move an item between columns by clicking on arrows that are inside the list item.
Right now I have a list of objects that I separate in 3 arrays depending on a "status" attribute. I would like to change that attribute when clicking on left/right arrow then refresh the UI with new arrays.

I haven't found the way to target the element that received the click.

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="todo in todoTodos" v-bind:key="todo._id">
    <span v-if="todo.importance == 1" class="bg-success"></span>
    <span v-else-if="todo.importance == 2" class="bg-warning"></span>
    <span v-else-if="todo.importance == 3" class="bg-alert"></span>
    <div>
      <h3>{{ todo.title }}</h3>
      <p>{{ todo.description }}</p>
    </div>
    <p class="todo__date">Début: {{ todo.datebegin }} - Fin espérée: {{ todo.dateend }}</p>
    <div class="todo__actions">
      <i @click="editTodo" class="icofont-edit"></i>
      <i @click="moveRight" class="icofont-arrow-right"></i>
      <i @click="moveLeft" class="icofont-arrow-left"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My linter prevents me from using v-for + v-if, but I guess that means I will have to re-calculate each list (todoTodos, doingTodos, doneTodos) after each modification. Is there a better way ?

I tried console.logging `this` `e.target` `e.currentTarget` but
`this` logs the entire data model
`e.target` and `e.currentTarget` logs the  element which I can't use to find my way back to the todo item I want to modify

Comment: Extend your `@click="moveRight"` to be `@click="moveRight(todo)"` then you can access the data on the clicked todo.

Answer (score 0):

You /usually/ pass the ($event) argument to a method if you want to access an event.

```
<i @click="moveLeft($event)" class="icofont-arrow-left"></i>
```

......

```
methods: {

moveLeft(e){

console.log(e.target)

}

}
```